# How to publish scala module in sonatype and maven?

Tags: scala, maven, module, sbt, sonatype

I have been trying publish module to sonatype but I am getting this exception--

```
[error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/johnny/.sbt/gpg/secring.asc (No such file or directory)
[error]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
[error]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.StreamingLoadable.loadFromFile(StreamingLoadable.scala:11)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.StreamingLoadable.loadFromFile$(StreamingLoadable.scala:11)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.SecretKeyRing$.loadFromFile(SecretKeyRing.scala:45)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.PGP$.loadSecretKeyRing(package.scala:31)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.cli.PgpStaticContext.secretKeyRing(context.scala:27)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.cli.PgpStaticContext.secretKeyRing$(context.scala:27)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.pgp.SbtPgpStaticContext.secretKeyRing(SbtPgpCommandContext.scala:9)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.cli.DelegatingPgpStaticContext.secretKeyRing(context.scala:34)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.pgp.cli.DelegatingPgpStaticContext.secretKeyRing$(context.scala:34)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.pgp.SbtPgpCommandContext.secretKeyRing(SbtPgpCommandContext.scala:14)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.pgp.BouncyCastlePgpSigner.$anonfun$keyId$1(PgpSigner.scala:37)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:12)
[error]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.pgp.BouncyCastlePgpSigner.<init>(PgpSigner.scala:37)
[error]     at com.typesafe.sbt.pgp.PgpSettings$.$anonfun$bcPgpSigner$1(PgpSettings.scala:111)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (Global / pgpSigner) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/johnny/.sbt/gpg/secring.asc (No such file or directory)
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 17, 2019 2:46:54 PM
```

I have tried many ways and and plugin setup instructions but getting different short of exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by this way:

1. check `$ gpg --version`

If do not have, install `gnupg`.

2. Then run `$ gpg --gen-key` to generate key.
   set `realm` , set `mail address`, set the `passphrase`

Key generation completed

3. check by `$ gpg --list-keys`

you will get this type result-

```
pub   rsa4096 2018-08-22 [SC]
      1234517530FB96F147C6A146A326F592D39AAAAA
uid           [ultimate] your name <you@example.com>
sub   rsa4096 2018-08-22 [E]
```

4. Now use this command to get public key block

   `$ gpg -a --export 1234517530FB96F147C6A146A326F592D39AAAAA`

Copy the whole text-

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

to

-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

Submit it pgp key servers, Wait some hours.

4.1 export secring.asc file to any location of your computer.
write this command

```
$ gpg -a --export-secret-keys > /home/johnny/secring.asc
```

4.2 Copy this file and place it to this location

**~/.sbt/gpg/secring.asc**

5. Now you will have to set up **sbt-pgp** plugin

To this **~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/gpg.sbt** file to enable it globally for SBT projects add this line- (if the gpg.sbt file does not exist create this there)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.1.1")
```

6. Go to **/home/$username/.gnugp** folder, if you see **pubring.kpx** file but not **secring.gpg** file, you do not need to add `useGpg := true` line in your module's build.sbt file. If secring.gpg file exists add `useGpg := true` in your module's build.sbt file.

6.1 run this command on your terminal to find out the gpg executable file in your machine

```
$ dpkg --listfiles gpg

/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/gpg
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gpg
/usr/share/doc/gpg/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/gpg.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/gpg/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gpg/changelog.Debian.gz
```

6.2 add this to **~/.sbt/gpg.sbt** file

```
gpgCommand := "/user/bin/gpg"
```

6.3 If in your **/home/$username/.gnugp** folder you have **secring.gpg** file you will have to add this to **~/.sbt/gpg.sbt** file by

```
pgpSecretRing := file("/path/to/my/secring.gpg")
```

For more information visit this [link](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-pgp/usage.html)

7. Now create this file **~/.sbt/1.0/sonatype.sbt**
   just add this line to the file

   `credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "sonatype_credential")`

7.1 Create JIRA account by this [link](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa)

7.2 By **create** button create an issue for opening your repository in sonatype
[image]

7.3 Create github repository or use your module related repository in issue creation form.

you will get idea about your form from this pic
[image]

7.4 Create a another repository with your issue's **OSSRH-XXXXX** string like this-
**githubusername/OSSRH-xxxx** . To verify your repository

You will have to wait some minutes to be approved. If your repo is approved you will get a mail.

8. Now create this file **~/.sbt/sonatype_credential**, just add this line and in pass and username - set your JIRA password and username respectively.

   ```
    realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
    host=oss.sonatype.org
    user=username
    password=password
   ```
9. in your module's build.sbt file set this configuration---

   ```
    ThisBuild / organization := "com.example.project2"
    ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"
    ThisBuild / organizationHomepage := Some(url("http://example.com/"))

    ThisBuild / scmInfo := Some(
    ScmInfo(
    url("https://github.com/your-account/your-project"),
    "scm:git@github.com:your-account/your-project.git"
     )
    )


    ThisBuild / developers := List(
       Developer(
       id    = "Your identifier",
       name  = "Your Name",
       email = "your@email",
       url   = url("http://your.url")
        )
       )

     ThisBuild / description := "Some descripiton about your project."
     ThisBuild / licenses := List("Apache 2" -> new URL("http://www.apache.org      /licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"))
     ThisBuild / homepage := Some(url("https://github.com/example/project"))

      // Remove all additional repository other than Maven Central from POM
     ThisBuild / pomIncludeRepository := { _ => false }
     ThisBuild / publishTo := {
     val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
     if (isSnapshot.value) Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
     else Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
      }
     ThisBuild / publishMavenStyle := true
   ```

Now run **publishSigned**
on your sbt project.

Now you can check your upload by this link

**https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/$yourgitUserName/$repoName**

or login https://oss.sonatype.org/ and search by your module name

[image]